# Decompress RAW image before passing it to CIFilter?

Tags: objective-c, swift, image, compression, cifilter

I have a .RAF file which is a Fujifilm compressed RAW image format. CIFilter is able to read the RAW data. However, I need to decompress the RAW data before passing it to CIFilter. Is this possible using Objective C or Swift? I looked into Fujifilm's RAW tools and could not find such a feature anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: .... X-H1, maybe?  Unless Fuji makes a library available to decompress their RAW, you're out of luck.  You'll have to contact them.

Comment: "I need to decompress the RAW data before passing it to CIFilter." Why? What are you trying to do with it?